# Eclipse won't switch workspace

Tags: eclipse, lombok

Whenever I switch workspace on eclipse, I get the error:

An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
Duplicate field name&signature in class file org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/ast/ASTNode

If I restart Eclipse, it then loads the new workspace correctly. Any ideas  how I go about fixing this?

I'm using  Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7

Comment: I just encountered the same error. Do you happen to have the Groovy plugin installed? Any other plugins that may have caused this?

Comment: I don't have the Groovy plugin on mine. It happened around the time I installed the plugin for the Spring framework for me

Comment: What about Lombok? I too installed STS at some point. I think this may be related.

Comment: I'm getting this. No groovy plugin, but I do have the Gradle plugin (included in STS I believe, though I don't have STS itself). Do have lombok too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, whoops, lombok bug. Sorry. It's been fixed; the next lombok version (looks like that'll be 1.14) will no longer have this issue. Until then, the edge release can be used if this is really cramping your workspace-switchin' style :)

http://projectlombok.org/download-edge.html

Comment: answered by THE source. :)

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of projectlombok.

Comment: I do have Lombok - seems like this might be something we all have in common. Mine is already the latest version though. Did installing that work for you?

Comment: Yes, although I was getting the same error at a different point in time (opening Java files), so maybe there's an extra fix required somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  After updating Gradle and anything else that I had installed in Eclipse, it still wouldn't work.  For me it actually wouldn't be fixed by restarting Eclipse, as far as I could tell.  I managed to fix it by downloading the latest release of Eclipse and extracting it over my current installation.  Don't know if that'll work for you or not.